# IGNORE INTO Mysql not ignoring record

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my sql code to load csv file into database but i have lots of duplicate code generated by perl script. I want to ignore duplicate records while inserting into DB and it's work but every time it inserts one duplicate record you can see in screenshot.

```
load data local infile '" . public_path() . "/temp_data.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE temp_data fields terminated by ','
                      enclosed by '\"'
                      lines terminated by '\n'
                      IGNORE 1 LINES
                      (state, city, category, business, contact, address, phone, website, email)";
            $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '0r@ng3cr33d', 'yourserv');
```

[image]

Table Scheme :

[image]

[image]

Why ? i am using unique key on column email but still it's adding duplicate.

One thing i noticed when load csv into database it's picking \r word in some records, anyone know how i can ignore that ? maybe that's why it inserting second one.

Example :

[image]

1 : info@480water.com
2 : info@480water.com\r

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps, you think, that you use unique key on column email, but in reality you do not. Without table schema, it is impossible to give you any help. Besides, I advise you to throw MySQL away and migrate to Postgres as fast as possible. If you do not follow the last advice right away, in several weeks/months/years you will do.

Comment: I just looking into records and found in some records it's inserting \r word do you know how i can ignore while inserting ?

Comment: I guess, it is much easier to prepare csv files - remove unnecessary "\r" and after that do the import.

Comment: yes you are right but i don't have script access, records sent by client, but still should need a solution.

Comment: Hm. It seems like you can modify your PHP code, so you can do all this preparation in PHP.

Comment: yes, that's what my question - i am trying to load csv file is there a way i can ignore that while inserting ?

Comment: You can do it not "while inserting", but "before inserting". Read this csv file in PHP and replace all "\r" with "" and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this :

```
lines terminated by '\r\n'
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working - just spent my two days on this - never thought it would be this easy :)